# Game Center Leaderboard Issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, game-center

I have successfully put game center leaderboards into my app with them updating the highscores correctly so I'm not worried about that.
The problem I am having is even though they are displaying and updating correctly in my app, when I view the leaderboards in the game center app it says there are no scores???
Anyone else has this trouble???

Disco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is just a delay between the gamecenter servers and the saving of highscores when developing.

Answer (score 0):

While you develop your app all scores get submitted to the sandbox gamecenter servers.

Maybe you are logged in the live servers with the game center app ?

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback. No I just checked. I'm definitely logged into the sandbox account?! Very odd eh